# How to change a custom NavigationItem title and background color?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Earlier I used a navigationcontroller with this code :

`self.navigationItem.title = @"News";`

Now I have the problem that I no longer needed the navigationcontroller as I am using a page controller for navigation. Now I added a navigationbar however it doesn't change the title with this code anymore.

Also how can I change the background color?

Answer (score 3):

IN iOS 7 use write following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if ([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) 
{
     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 4.0/255.0 green:173.0/255.0 blue:214.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f ]]; //// change background color of navigationBar
     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; /// set backButton color of navigation bar
     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}]; // set title color 
     [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  /// set all barButton item color
     self.navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;// set translucent NO
}
```

Use as per your requirement.

Comment: This sets the background color thanks but I still need to figure out why the title isn't set perhaps I can do that in appDelegate aswell as I was working in the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

So there is some magic happening when you use a navigation controller that you don't see and now that you've made the switch to justing using a navigation bar you lose that magic.

Navigation bars are responsible for managing and presenting UNavigationItems, and as such hold an array of them.  A NavigationItem holds things like left and right buttons, and the title or titleView.  When your navigation controller pushes a new controller, it creates a brand new UINavigation item then links it to your new view controller, and then pushes that onto navigation bars stack of nav items.  That's why from within your view controller you set the title with self.navigationItem.title instead of referencing the navbar.

Basically you have to manage the bar and nav items yourself now.  This should about do it for you:

```
_navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yOffset, CGRectGetHeight(size), height)];
_navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My navbar title"];
[_navBar setItems:@[_navItem]];

[self.view addSubview:_navBar];
```

Of course you'll have to manage the size a bit differently as my example comes from an app where it's being used in landscape mode.